# PHP: counting arcctg and ctg

Tags: php, trigonometry

is there any function in PHP which would get the cotangent and arccotangent of my number?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [tan](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tan.php) function in the PHP manual for the cotangent, notably the comment [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tan.php#93461) for cotangents

```
<?php
//FOR PHP 4
function cot($rad)
{
    return tan(M_PI_2 - rad2deg($rad));
}

//FOR PHP 3
function cot($rad)
{
    return tan(M_PI/2 - rad2deg($rad));
}
?>
```

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.atan.php) for #2

Comment: This is not correct solution. You shouldn't use rad2deg() function here, because the argument of tan function is radian value.

Answer (score 1):

And arccotangent(a) would be atan(1/a).

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.atan.php

theres a cotan funciton in teh comments for http://php.net/manual/en/function.tan.php

Answer (score 0):

[`tan`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tan.php) will give you the tangent. Cotangent is `1/tan`. You can easily use the `arctan` function to calculate the arccotan taking in mind that

```
arccot x = (PI / 2) - arctan x
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are no built-ins for those. So you'll have to write/find some. Cot is in the comments for tan() on php.net

http://php.net/manual/en/function.tan.php